# Decode HTML entities in Kotlin

Tags: html, json, kotlin, decode, html-entities

How can I decode html entities in Kotlin ? I tried this

```
Fuel.get("...").responseJson { request, response, result ->
    println("Reponse : "+response.toString())
    //do something with response
    result.fold({
        json ->
        Log.i("json", Html.escapeHtml(json.content)) //.escapeHtml, like "fromHtml" is deprecated
    }, {
        err ->
        Log.i("error", err.toString())
    })
}
```

but I've still this :

```
[{\"title\":\"La R\\u00e9gion responsable de l\\u2019organisation de tous vos transports interurbains\", ...
```

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: I want to have "Région" instead of " R\\u00e9gion"